# Can we use the Yammer search API v2? Is it official?

Tags: yammer

When searching in Yammer it uses an `/api/v2/search` endpoint like this:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v2/search/models?search=test&start=0&size=20&model_types=threads&_network=xxxxxxx&relevance=DEFAULT

Compared to the [v1 search endpoint](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/searchjson) this returns more data. We need this data. And we successfully tested using this v2 endpoint.

**Now the question:** Is this v2 search endpoint safe to use? Is it "official"? Maybe somebody from Yammer reads along - on their [Help](https://developer.yammer.com/page/support) page it says:

> We encourage you to post all programming questions to StackOverflow
>   with a #yammer hashtag

So here we are. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just found another question about the API v2 release date - from 2016. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459558/possible-yammer-rest-api-v2-release-date This and a possible future of the API in the Microsoft Graph could point to the v2 API being pretty stable now....

Answer (score 2):

The Yammer v2 search API endpoint is not yet officially supported for third-party use. This is because we anticipate the need to make changes to it as we build it out. There are no plans to lock developers out of experimenting with the v2 search API. However, when developing any important functionality against this API, automated testing should be used to detect any unannounced breaking changes that we make while we continue to build it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. Who must I bribe to get any documentation about the different v2 search properties and sub-endpoints?